# GitHub private repo updates using electron updater

Tags: github

Im updating my application with electron auto updater it usually worked but now im randomly getting this error . Idk if this is a valid error but here is the error that I see.

```
Error in auto-updater. Error: Unable to find latest version on GitHub (https://api.github.com/repos/rayisooo/sneekshot/releases/latest), please ensure a production release exists: HttpError: 404 
 "method: GET url: https://api.github.com/repos/rayisooo/sneekshot/releases/latest\n\nPlease double check that your authentication token is correct. Due to security reasons actual status maybe not reported, but 404.\n"
Headers: {
  "server": "GitHub.com",
  "date": "Tue, 14 Dec 2021 20:51:40 GMT",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 "x-oauth-scopes": "public_repo, read:repo_hook",
 "x-accepted-oauth-scopes": "repo",
 "github-authentication-token-expiration": "<stripped sensitive data>",
 "x-github-media-type": "github.v3; format=json",
 "x-ratelimit-limit": "5000",
 "x-ratelimit-remaining": "4999",
 "x-ratelimit-reset": "1639518700",
 "x-ratelimit-used": "1",
 "x-ratelimit-resource": "core",
 "access-control-expose-headers": "ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset",
 "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
 "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload",
 "x-frame-options": "deny",
 "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
 "x-xss-protection": "0",
 "referrer-policy": "origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
 "content-security-policy": "default-src 'none'",
 "vary": "Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With",
 "content-encoding": "gzip",
 "x-github-request-id": "A456:3715:9B17C4:18B8F84:61B903DC"
}
at createHttpError     (/Volumes/RAYDRIVE/electronProjects/sneeskshotRELEASE/dist/mac/Sneekshot.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-updater/node_modules/builder-util-runtime/out/httpExecutor.js:14)
at ElectronHttpExecutor.handleResponse (/Volumes/RAYDRIVE/electronProjects/sneeskshotRELEASE/dist/mac/Sneekshot.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-updater/node_modules/builder-util-runtime/out/httpExecutor.js:106)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Volumes/RAYDRIVE/electronProjects/sneeskshotRELEASE/dist/mac/Sneekshot.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/electron-updater/node_modules/builder-util-runtime/out/httpExecutor.js:73)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315)
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:105)
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (events.js:315)
```

anyone know what might be the issue with GitHub because I did check to see if there is an active release and there is

Comment: Same problem, updater working perfectly in dev, but fails with this error in production